# I want to hide the query parameters from the URL. How can i achieve the same?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working in an application where I am listing the list of candidate. When I click on the candidate name, it should open a new tab with the candidate details.

I am storing the respective candidateId in the local storage and opening window in a new tab where I am retrieving the candidate id from local storage and getting the data.

The problem I am facing is , if I open multiple candidates in new tabs, the candidateId is getting overridden with the latest candidateId. So, if I refresh the candidate details page which is in a new tab, getting the data of the latest opened candidate.

I thought of sending the candidateId in query param and hiding the query param.

Can anyone suggest me how to do that or any other alternative?

Comment: Use a DB to store data and, on a new page, retrieve the relative information by the id or something like it. But if you just want to do it using local storage, simply store each object information into an object in the local storage. This way you can simply acess the data as I said before, with an id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FormData interface

```
public getCondidate(id: string): Observable<Condidate> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('condidateId', id);
    return this.http.post<Condidate>(%server_Url%, formData);
}
```

Use can retrieve the Id in backend by querying the parameter "condidateId" in the Query.
This way the query params will contain the condidateId by it will be not shown in the url unsell you use the developer tools and inspect the query in Network section.

Don't save the condidateId in the localStorage unless you have a login or an authentication mechanism. When you list all the condidates after retrieving them from the DB, the method that you call onClick to open a page with the correspending details should be called with the corresponding ID. For example

```
<div
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="condidate of condidates">
      <button (click)="getCondidate(condidate.id)">Get Condidate</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The getCondidate(condidate.id) method should call the previous code.

Hope it helps.